# MongoDB findOne query depends of result

Tags: mongodb, nosql

lets say that I have collection of something and record can look like that:

```
{
    '_id' : MongoId('xxxxxx'),
    'dir' : '/home/',
    'category' : 'catname',
    'someData' : 'very important info'
}
```

Is it possible to make **only one** query like *collection.findOne({????}, {'someData' : 1});* to find colection matching this:

> find by dir, if not found search for category name, if there is still
>   nothing find collection with category name is 'default'

or at least, can I say in this query that I want first match dir and if not found I want match category

```
collection.findOne({
    $or : [
        {'dir' : 'someCondition'},
        {'category' : 'someCondition'}
    ]
});
```

Comment: well... do the $or query and put the logic in the code, where the logic is supposed to be!?

Comment: if I do $or with findOne, it will return first match, so I will have no idea is it what I wanted. Of course logic supposed to be in code, but in this particular case I need it in query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { '$project':
        {
            //Keep existing fields
            '_id':1,
            'dir':1,
            'category':1,
            'someData':1,
            //Compute some new values
            'sameDir': {'$eq':['$dir', 'SOMEDIR']},
            'sameCategory': {'$eq':['$dir', 'SOMECATEGORY']},
            'defaultCategory': {'$eq':['$dir', 'default']},
        }
    },
    { '$sort':
        {
            'sameDir': -1,
            'sameCategory': -1,
            'defaultCategory': -1,
        }
    },
    { '$limit': 1 }
])
```

The `$sort` will keep true values first, so a directory match will come first, followed by a category match, finally followed by a default category. The `$limit:1` will keep the one on top (ie. the best match). Of course, make sure to input your own `SOMEDIR` and `SOMECATEGORY` values.